# Does convergence of $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ imply $a_n/n$ converges to zero?

Tags: convergence-divergence

If for $a_n \geq 0$, the mean $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ converges, then does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Let $s_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$. Then $a_n=ns_n-(n-1)s_{n-1}$ and 
$$\frac{a_n}n=s_n-\Big(1-\frac1n\Big)s_{n-1}\to 0$$
 as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This answer received quite a handful of up and down votes. Can we maybe discuss what we like or don't like about this? I thought it wasn't true and had an idea similar to Jack's.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: Jack's example is wrong. This is a simple derivation. It is easy to judge whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Right, and the point of my question is to determine where the impasse is. Maybe that way some of the downvoters will switch them to upvotes. It appears Jack's answer was deleted anyway. I guess that also settles the issue.

Comment: Jack you are mistaken.

Comment: @uniquesolution: you are right guys, sorry for the mess and (+1) to Hans.

Comment: Alfred, upvotes and downvotes are very dynamic, emotional, abrupt, spontaneous, and have little to do with mathematics, in general.

Comment: @Rajat: If you like my answer, please accept it.